# Subdomain vs Totally New Domain

Tags: seo, google, domains, subdomain

I have a **web design and development agency**. Assume that domain name is example.com.

1. I have plan to publish new tools like IP checker, Grammar checker, Domain Age Checker.

So I thought to use tools.example.com for those tools.

2. I have plan to start a community like inbound.org, bizsugar.com for bloggers, webmasters .

So I thought to use web.example.com for that community.

And there are many ideas.........................

**If I use same domain with sub domains it is easily for me to manage. And I don't need to create separate email address and I don't want to renew multiple domain.** So I like it.

**But,**

I saw some disadvantages (I am not sure those are correct).

1. If one sub domain has low quality posts, is it affect for my main domain also?
2. If Google penalize for main domain or sub domain is it affect for other sub domains?

So my question is, for my requirements,

Is it ok to use 3,4 sub domains or use complete new 3,4 domains? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Go with sub domains, When the product/service success with sub domain move to a new domain :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, just as a precaution as soon as you see there will be a possibility of things may be going wrong (Possible poor approach of SEO) then think about placing at a different domain in terms of reputation.

Having number of sub-domains for different needs are perfectly all right.

Meaning, you may keep and have number of sub-domains for different needs provided they will be clean.

To answer your question about using 3,4 sub domains.

Advantages / Disadvantages:

- You can easily manage from hosting side.
- You might need to be careful putting several things at one place, let's say if your one product may get infected with the virus, it may impact your entire hosting. So, security will be an important aspect to consider.
- You may also, consider having those sub-domains as you planned and once you feel the product might start to do well then you may move (301) that subdomain to a new domain.

Comment: Thaks for the answer. But I did not get a answer for this two questions. 1. If one sub domain has low quality posts, is it affect for my main domain also? 2. 
If Google penalize for main domain or sub domain is it affect for other sub domains?

Comment: 1). If there will be no cross-linking then the low-quality post shouldn't impact the main domain.

2) If you will have cross-linking between main domain and subdomain then yes the impact will be on main domain too.

Even if you may not have cross-linking if particular subdomain will get penalised it will definitely impact the main domain indirectly in terms of reputation.

Comment: There is link for sub domains in navigation bar of main domain. Is it also consider as cross-linking ?

Comment: Yes. I would say if any of your subdomains may have possibility going things wrong, it wouldn't be recommended to keep on the main server as a subdomain with a link, may cause serious issues.